# How do I set the 'value' in my Zend form checkbox?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

The Zend Form is proving to be a bit tricky for me, even as much as I am working with it lately...

I have this form and I am attempting to dynamically create the several checkboxes for it. It is working out alright, except I cannot seem to get the 'value' attribute to change.

In my Zend form class I have this snippet...

```
// psychotic symptoms
        $this->addElement('checkbox', 'psychoticsymptom', array(
                'label' => 'psychoticsymptom',
                'name' => 'psychoticsymptom',
        ));
```

In my view (phtml) I am calling it like this...

```
<div class="element">
    <?php // Psychotic Symptoms
    $Criteria = new Criteria();
    $Criteria->add( DictionaryPeer::CATEGORY, 'MAR: Psychotic Symptoms' );
    $Criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn( 'Ordinal' );
    $this->PsychoticSymptomsList = DictionaryPeer::doSelect( $Criteria );

    foreach( $this->PsychoticSymptomsList as $Symptom ) {

        $form->psychoticsymptom->setValue($Symptom->getDictionaryId());
        $form->psychoticsymptom->setAttrib('name', $Symptom->getWord());

        echo $Symptom->getDictionaryId(); // prove my id is coming through... (it is)
        $form->psychoticsymptom->getDecorator('label')->setTag(null);

        echo $form->psychoticsymptom->renderViewHelper();
        $form->psychoticsymptom->setLabel($Symptom->getWord());
        echo $form->psychoticsymptom->renderLabel();
        echo '<br />';
                    }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except the value attribute on each checkbox is rendering a value of '1'. I have tried moving the 'setValue' line to several different positions, as to set the value before the form element renders but I am having no luck getting this to work. It's worth any effort to me because I need to do the same type of operation in many areas of my application. I would have done this a bit different too, but I am re-factoring another application and am trying to keep some things unchanged (like the database for instance).

Any help is much appriciated
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try to overwrite the "checkedValue" and "uncheckedValue". check this [reference](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Form/Element/Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox.html)

```
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'psychoticsymptom', array(
                'label' => 'psychoticsymptom',
                'name' => 'psychoticsymptom',
                'checkedValue' => 'checked Value',
                'uncheckedValue' => 'unchecked Value'
        ));
```

Comment: That totally did it! Thanks... I changed 'setValue' to 'setCheckedValue' in the 'foreach' loop. This will solve the same problem in other sections as well and I know I can make it behave exactly like the old app, with improvements of course. They have certain limitations though, it's a medical app (if you couldn't tell :) ) and those can be a bit funny about stuff. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only have one psychoticsymptom element "checkbox" which your adding (changing) the value too for each $this->PsychoticSymptomsList.

Maybe you would be better off using a multicheckbox element instead.

Comment: Good idea, I will have to check if the form is allowed to have more than one checked as well. Thanks!

Comment: I may be bound to using checkboxes, some of my forms are not very flexible in scope, although I have to check with the client... they may not have wanted the ability to check multiple boxes either. Wonder if a radio button setup would work? Have to look into this...